# Custom list implementation iterator can't access last element (c++)

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm implementing a custom list for a personal project & I can't seem to access the last element with an iterator.

It's basically a flat doubly linked list (with next & previous node pointers).

**expression.hpp**

```
#ifndef TPP_EXPRESSION_HPP
#define TPP_EXPRESSION_HPP

#include <cstddef>
#include <globals.hpp>
#include "node.hpp"
#include "iterator.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace tpp {
namespace expression {
class Expression {
    std::size_t _size;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

public:
    void print() {
        Node* node = left;
        while (node != nullptr) {
            std::cout << node->value << "\t";
            node = node->next;
        }
    }

    void append(byte val) {
        Node* node = new Node(val);
        if (right != nullptr) {
            Node* tmp = right;
            tmp->next = node;
            right = node;
            right->prev = tmp;
        } else {
            left = right = node;
        }
        _size++;
    }

    Iterator begin() {
        std::cout << "Left: " << left->value << std::endl;
        return Iterator(left);
    }

    const ConstIterator cbegin() const {
        return ConstIterator(left);
    }

    Iterator end() {
        std::cout << "Right: " << right->value << std::endl;
        return Iterator(right);
    }

    const ConstIterator cend() const {
        return ConstIterator(right);
    }

    bool is_empty() {
        return _size == 0;
    }

    std::size_t size() {
        return _size;
    }

    Expression() : _size(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
    }

    ~Expression() {
        Node* node = right;
        while (node != nullptr) {
            Node* old_back = node;
            node = node->prev;
            delete old_back;
        }
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
};
} // expression
} // tpp
#endif //TPP_EXPRESSION_HPP
```

**iterator.hpp**

```
#ifndef TPP_EXPRESSION_ITERATOR_HPP
#define TPP_EXPRESSION_ITERATOR_HPP

#include <globals.hpp>
#include "node.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace tpp {
namespace expression {

class Iterator {
    Node* node;
public:
    Iterator(Node* ptr) : node(ptr) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator& rhs) : node(rhs.node) {}
    Iterator& operator++() { std::cout << "Current: " << node->value << std::endl; node = node->next; std::cout << "Now: " << node->value << std::endl;return *this; }
    Iterator& operator--() { node = node->prev; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) { bool stats = node != rhs.node; std::cout << (stats ? "Not equal" : "Equal") << std::endl;  return stats; }
    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) { return node == rhs.node; }
    byte& operator*() { std::cout << "Dereferencing " << node->value << std::endl; return node->value; }
};

class ConstIterator {
    const Node* node;
public:
    ConstIterator(const Node* ptr) : node(ptr) {}
    ConstIterator(const ConstIterator& rhs) : node(rhs.node) {}
    ConstIterator& operator++() { node = node->next; return *this; }
    ConstIterator& operator--() { node = node->prev; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(const ConstIterator& rhs) { return node != rhs.node; }
    bool operator==(const ConstIterator& rhs) { return node == rhs.node; }
    const byte& operator*() const { return node->value; }
};
} // expression
} // tpp
#endif //TPP_EXPRESSION_ITERATOR_HPP
```

**node.hpp**

```
#ifndef TPP_EXPRESSION_NODE_HPP
#define TPP_EXPRESSION_NODE_HPP
#include <globals.hpp>

namespace tpp {
namespace expression {
struct Node {
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    byte value;
    Node(byte value) : value(value), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
    Node() : value('\0'), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
};
}
} // tpp
#endif //TPP_EXPRESSION_NODE_HPP
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <globals.hpp>
#include <expression/include.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    tpp::expression::Expression e;
    e.append('0');
    e.append('1');
    e.append('0');
    e.append('1');
    for (auto elem : e) {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
    e.print();
}
```

**Example output**

```
Left: 0
Right: 1
Not equal
Dereferencing 0
0
Current: 0
Now: 1
Not equal
Dereferencing 1
1
Current: 1
Now: 0
Not equal
Dereferencing 0
0
Current: 0
Now: 1
Equal
0       1       0       1
```

Code is a mess, I was more focused on getting it working before I cleaned it up. Any help would be useful, thanks.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `print`:

```
void print() {
    Node* node = left;
    while (node != nullptr) {
        std::cout << node->value << "\t";
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

You iterate until you have the past-last-element in `node`. The same is true for range-based for loops: `end(..)` will not be reached. So change

```
Iterator end() {
    return Iterator(right);
}
```

to

```
Iterator end() {
    return Iterator(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: I must've completely spaced out over this. I've opted to instead have a terminator node (which is part of my spec anyway). Thanks for pointing this out!